# Variables not matching/returning against for csv.DictReader values

Tags: python, csv

I have a question regarding how to match variables to DictReader headers and rows.

I have the below set from a CSV:

```
OrderedDict([('name', 'Bob'), ('cash', '2'), ('food', '8'), ('drink', '11')])
OrderedDict([('name', 'Mary'), ('cash', '3'), ('food', '9'), ('drink', '2')])
```

I also have variables I'm taking from another file.

`maximum_number` is a counter of the greatest repeating categories, and `maximum_category` is the associated category.

```
with open(database_name, newline='') as csvfile:
    dictionary = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in dictionary:
        if maximum_number in row[maximum_category]:
            print(row['name'])
```

For example, if `maximum_category` is food and the `maximum_number` is 9, I want to return `Mary` (from name) from the above two sets. If the category is drink and number is 11, I want to return `Bob`.

I'm in the middle of experimenting with Python, so I'm probably missing something basic, but I would like some advice as to why the above won't work and what's the best way to go about it.

Comment: You didn't say whether you were getting an error message or just an unexpected result - since the definition of `maximum_number` isn't given, it's impossible to say which one you're getting. However `maximum_number in row[maximum_category]` probably doesn't do what you expect, `row[maximum_category]` is a string, going by the example data you provided, so `x in row[maximum_category]` will see if `x` is in that string. If `x` is an integer (as you suggest), that will cause an error, if it is a string, Python will return if `x` is a substring of that string, also not what you want.

Comment: @Grismar You're exactly right. I overlooked converting my integer values to strings, and this is now resolved by a simple str(maximum_number). That was dumb of me to forget, thank you vey much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't indicated exactly how your code "won't work", but it seems to for me. Here's a runnable example using the following .csv file:

```
name,cash,food,drink
Bob,2,8,11
Mary,3,9,2
```

Code:

```
import csv

database_name = 'ordered_dict_test.csv'

maximum_category = 'food'
maximum_number = '9'
with open(database_name, newline='') as csvfile:
    dictionary = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in dictionary:
        if maximum_number in row[maximum_category]:
            print(row['name'])

maximum_category = 'drink'
maximum_number = '11'
with open(database_name, newline='') as csvfile:
    dictionary = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in dictionary:
        if maximum_number in row[maximum_category]:
            print(row['name'])
```

And prints the following:

```
Mary
Bob
```

I suspect the problem might be not realizing that all the data read and returned by the `DictReader` are strings.

Comment: I've written elsewhere in the comments, but you're right. My problem was that maximum_number was an integer rather than a string. str(maximum_number) solved this.